# SharePoint 2016 & Project server 2016

Tags: 2016, project-server

I am trying to use Microsoft Project server with SharePoint and I can't find any resources showing how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you getting started with `Project Server 2016`, you should be aware of the following points:

- Project Server 2016 runs as a service application in SharePoint Server 2016.
- A separate installation is no longer required as it was in previous versions of Project Server 2010 /2013.
- The SharePoint Server 2016 MSI file will contain the installation files for Project Server 2016 as well.
- Project Server 2016 is only available on SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise.

So you only need to [install SharePoint 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493) and [configure Project Server Application service](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/install-and-configure-project-server-2016/) to can work with Project server 2016.

---

**Regarding Resources,**

- If you need to know How to configure Project Server 2016 check [Install and Configure Project Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/install-and-configure-project-server-2016/)
- Also check [Simply, What’s new and deprecated features in Project Server 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/29/simply-whats-new-and-deprecated-features-in-project-server-2016/)
- You can also check [Project Server 2016 Configuration](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37674.project-server-2016-configuration.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response! However when I add a site collection and chose       the Project template I get an error

Comment: In project server 2016 you don't need to choose the site template as project you should enable it via PowerShell as mentioned **[Install and Configure Project Server 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/install-and-configure-project-server-2016/)** please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Also please should you tell me your scenario or what you need to do specifically to can help you faster :)

Comment: I'am at step: "Creating a Project Server service application"
I have already one there! what should I do leave it or delete it and create another one ?

Comment: great you run that Enable-ProjectServerLicense -Key, right then go to create Project Server service application? what is the next step that you have to do ? you should follow all the steps as I have mentioned. by the way, I am the author of this article so if you confused at any step tell me

Comment: Thx!
When I type the command "New-SPSite -ContentDatabase PWA_Content -URL http://epm/sites/PWA -Template pwa#0" with my own info in I receive this error:
This page has encountred a critical error. Contact your system...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53404/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-mohamed-ayach).